# Unity ads not shown while testing game

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, ads

I'm working on my game in Unity over 2 months. I have question about Unity Ads. 
This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class myAds : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start () 
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize ("1017331", true);

        StartCoroutine (ShowAdWhenReady());
    }

    IEnumerator ShowAdWhenReady()
    {
        while (!Advertisement.IsReady())
            yield return null;

        Advertisement.Show ();
    }
}
```

I made a new scene only for ads, and I invoke ads in " lose " script with -> Application.LoadLevel ("name of ads scene ") every time when I lose.

Now, display screen says that " Here would be your Ad unit ". Will be appeared real ads when the game gets on the App Store / Google Play? 
I tested my game via Unity Remote 4, and I have the same message on my display.